# copy(): Filename cannot be empty - for some files

Tags: php, file-upload

when I am trying to upload some videos to the server I get this error:

> copy(): Filename cannot be empty

I only get this for some videos and not for all of them, but all of them are mp4.

the code is:

```
$video_name = uniqid().'.'.$extension;
$newname="videos/".$video_name;
$copied = copy($_FILES['video_src']['tmp_name'], $newname);
```

And both `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are setto 50Mb while the videos are smaller than 10Mb.

Any idea?

Comment: Why aren't you using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)?

Comment: Can you `echo $_FILES['video_src']['tmp_name']` befor you `copy()` it? What's it say?

Comment: Its empty, show nothing.
I tried to replace it to move_uploaded_file() but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function. Also, you should probably change `$newname`:

```
$video_name = uniqid().'.'.$extension;
$newname="./videos/".$video_name;
$orig = isset($_FILES['video_src']) && isset($_FILES['video_src']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['video_src']['tmp_name'] : '';
if (empty($orig)) {
  echo "Uploaded file doesn't exist.";
}
$copied = move_uploaded_file($orig, $newname);
// Optional
if ($copied) {
  echo "File moved.";
}
else {
  echo "File not moved.";
}
```

Comment: @assaf Can you temporarily replace your code with this: `print_r($_FILES);` and then post the output?

Comment: Array ( [video_src] => Array ( [name] => asd.mp4 [type] => video/mp4 [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpBFC4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 5510872 ) ) 1